# How to display images at the center of the page, and a button at bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

I want to display two images, side by side, at the center of the page, as well as display a button at bottom of the page.

Currently, the alignment of the two images is horizontally center.  But, what I want is the two images at center of the page.

#### Below is my code:

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.home {
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2483E8;
}
```

```html
<body align="center">
  <h2>Guidance</h2>
  <br>

  <table style="width:100%" id="haha">
  </table>
  <br>

  <img src="image/add.png" width="130px" height="130px">
  <img src="image/list.png" width="130px" height="130px">

  <br><br><br>
  <button class="button home" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'">HOME</button>
</body>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please show us your css code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `display: flex;` and use `align-items` to the elements centred vertically and `justify-content` to get them horizontally centred.

Now to get the button stick to the bottom, you can either use `position: absolute;` or `position: fixed;`

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #2483E8;
}

img:first-child {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=image+1">
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000/fff&text=image+2">


<button class="button home" onclick="window.location.href='index.html'">HOME</button>
```

Comment: where's the img_holder?

Comment: @BrettCaswell have edited with an explanation. Thanks

Comment: @Hawau you don't actually need `img_holder`, have removed it.

Comment: when i run this code, the image is not side by side

Comment: @Hawau then how is it?

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways of doing this in CSS. Position: absolute or fix or relative e.g

`.button{
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 0;
    }`

Currently, there is no high set so will only be centre to the height of the content.

Maybe have div wrapper with height 100vh.

Hope this help!